# Update user control on Main Window from Page in another solution

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

Ok, I'm being really thick here and am having a few minor issues which are turning into major ones in my head:

I have a MainWindow that houses a tab control into which I have several "apps" sitting which all have their own solutions. I have built a neat "loading" control which is housed in the main window but is hidden and is only displayed when one of the displayed pages has a button clicked. However, I don't seem to be able to access the user control from the page.

As an example, I have an admin page which controls users in a database which wotks fine. When I click on the submit button I want to make the user control visible on the MainWindow and when the function is finished to hide the control. I know how to unhide and hide the control just not how to access it. I have attached a representation of the file structure below so you can see the issue I have accessing the MainWindow in the main solution from say the pageAdmin.xaml.

I have been googalizing this for a while and can't seem to find a solution that works. Can anyone point me in the right direction? I am open to any suggestions about how to handle this.

Andy

[image: Solution Structure]

Answer (score 0):

Just to be sure: what do you mean with "apps"? Do you have one WPF application which hosts different components?
Maybe PRISM (Microsoft  Framework) is interesting for you. In PRISM you can dynamically load components from different dlls and host them in one WPF application. It has a build in messaging framwork which works very well and the diffetent dlls don't need any references among themselves.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't very clear was I, my bad!! It is one WPF application with different components. Because of business continuity the components can be used in standalone apps and we use the terminology of "apps" for the business so they can understand it better.